# Instagram access token to retrieve any user feed

Tags: access-token, instagram

Is it normal that I can get **any users** feed with the same access_token? Here are two examples. The first is from the test account, it is what I should have access to. And the second one is from the ImagineDragons's instagram feed.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/510573486/media/recent?access_token=510573486.ab7d4b6.d8b155be5d1a47c78f72616b4d942e8d

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/20282699/media/recent?access_token=510573486.ab7d4b6.d8b155be5d1a47c78f72616b4d942e8d

If so, why do I have to request an access_token in order to do the request?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The token is required so the API cannot be accessed anonymously.  Instagram photos are public unless the user has explicitly set their account to be private.  Therefore, it is normal to be able to access the feeds of any public user account with a single valid token.

A token does not circumvent users' settings.  If you try to access an account that is marked private you won't get any results and instead receive this response:

`{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know you could have a private account Instagram account. This make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Most apis work like this.  Even though you are requesting public data (ie Imagine Dragon's instagram feed) they want to know who is making the request. They are probably tracking it to make sure no one is making a billion calls a day or something.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Most APIs do require a client id which can identify which _app_ is making the request. Access tokens are used to identify which _user_ is trying to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

According to: [Instagram Developer Documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

The API call you are trying to make requires an `access_token` at all times. This is usually done to prevent bots which continously crawl through recent lists to fetch images and such. The only way Instagram could prevent this is via this `access_token` approach. Once you have the token, you are able to browse through any user's feeds as you would be able to do it on the webpage of the respective user. If you don't want the user to login to see a certain recent list, you could register a dummy account with Instagram, log that in once, and store its `access_token`, bundle it with your application and you will be able to request the recent feed without prompting the user to login. I am sure that this isn't an accepted way of solving this problem, mainly because according to the documentation the `access_token` might change at anytime, making your application nonfunctional. Of course, there are solutions even to this scenario. To summarize, I think if you want to request such a data without an `access_token`, try my 'solution'.

Comment: I knew all this. I was wondering why with a single access_token I could gather any users feed. The private accound make sens know.

Plus a simple bot could crwal pages from around the www to find such access_token in websites that makes theses javascript request. The token is right in the GET request.