# Instagram access_token returning BadRequest error

Tags: ruby, sinatra, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working with the Instagram gem and getting an unexpected bad request error when calling Instagram.user_recent_media.

```
get '/api/photos' do
    client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
    puts 'access token: ' << session[:access_token].inspect
    id = params[:id]

    photos = Instagram.user_recent_media(id, {:max_id => params[:max_id]})
end
```

It's throwing this error:

```
Instagram::BadRequest - GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/35099128/media/recent.json?client_id=12345&max_id=: 400: you cannot view this resource:
```

In the line where I put the access_token, it is printing out an access token so it clearly exists. When I curl the request I get the same error,

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

but when I paste the request into the Instagram API console I get the expected results (JSON of user photo data). This is a user who I follow. For a little while I was having my access_token seemingly expire immediately and throwing a specific 'access token not valid' error but that has gone away, so I'm not sure what else could be causing this error.

Comment: Just out of curriosity, in the api console do you put `max_id=`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with and without `max_id` and it works either way in the API console. I'm using that in my app to keep cycling through a user's media since you can only grab a max of 20 items at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `access_token` or `client_id` that you are using in your Ruby code must be different from the one you are using in your web browser when you test the Instagram API console. That is the only explanation.

The ID that you are using in your question (**35099128**) is for a private Instagram account. The reason it works in the Instagram API console is because you are already following the private account with your Instagram account.

EDIT

To be 100% sure you have the correct `access_token` in your code you can try to make the query directly without the extraneous variables. Use the following format (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280551/instagram-access-token-to-retrieve-any-user-feed)):

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/20282699/media/recent?access_token=510573486.ab7d4b6.d8b155be5d1a47c78f72616b4d942e8d

Replace the user-id and `access_token` with the one your are printing in your code.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/35099128/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

EDIT2

Since the `access_token` is definitely valid, it is clear that your request formed in the Ruby code is missing the `access_token`. The problem is this line:

```
photos = Instagram.user_recent_media(id, {:max_id => params[:max_id]})
```

has no knowledge of your `access_token`, likely because you're are not using the `client` object that you previously defined. Try changing it to this (or the proper equivalent):

```
photos = client.user_recent_media(id, {:max_id => params[:max_id]})
```

Comment: In the API, I'm authenticated as the same user in the console as in my app., so I should have the same permissions based on which private users I am following...no? I don't understand why I would have a different access token. Also, re: the client_id, I am copying the request from my terminal so it's coming directly from my Ruby code.

Comment: @thisAnneM see the edit to my answer. I think something must be different between your code and the API console. Although, I suppose it conceivable that Instagram doesn't allow you to make any API calls to query information on private users.

Comment: Pasting my logged access_token into the request works as expected in the browser and curl.

Comment: That means your request formed in the Ruby code is missing the `access_token`. See my edit again.

Comment: Thanks a million! I added the token to the options hash (found in this commit: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/commit/503935f263060ced2f17cbab2ff0572da80292ca).

`photos = Instagram.user_recent_media(id, {:access_token => session[:access_token], :max_id => params[:max_id]})`